# Playing music lags on android Libgdx

Tags: android, audio, libgdx

I am developing a game for Android and iOS using Libgdx framework , and I am about to finish developing the game. The problem that I am facing right now is streaming music in the game. When the music is played, the game has no problem when played in desktop but when I play it in android (using LG G4) there is a lag in the game or slight frames drop every half a second, making it unplayable, despite trying all type of file formats eg: mp3,wav and ogg (my music is 15 seconds long). I tried playing it on android without streaming music and it had no problems at all, even though there is a tiny bit of lag occasionally but still playable. I tried using the Sound class for streaming music and there was no lag when playing on android but the music was not played completely, only a bit of the music was played like around 4-5 seconds. So now I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or the Music class is not compatible with Android OS.

PS: This is my first time making a game and took me a almost 4 months to develop. I developed this game by reading the Libgdx wiki and following the guides from the Simple game shown in the wiki. I did not use Asset Manager to load my resources nor I used Texture Atlas to load my Textures. Could this be a problem? Thanks a ton!

Comment: only thing I could add - `Sound` is designed for short audio files. [This](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=33829.0) _might_ help as well.

Comment: provide me code for music play ?? How you load  and initialize music in your game

Comment: What are you using Music or Sound class of libgdx framework for music.

Comment: @1blustone I have seen this forum but I did not do much research on it, will definitely do this time

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I am using libgdx Music class for the music. I initialize my music exactly the way it is shown here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game